# What does "about now" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I know you're feeling pretty hey sailor up here about now.

- What does *about now* mean, in the sentence?
- Is it an informal way of saying?

Comment: I thought it was bizarre that OP should be asking about the *about now* in a sentence that makes no sense whatsoever. Thanks to [@mplungian](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119190/quotes) I see where the sentence came from. To my mind it's not a real question, it's complete drivel, and I've voted to close.

Comment: @fumblefingers: My name is not Armenian :| But yes, it is likely drivel, but about now still makes sense. Seem my edited answer

Comment: @mplungjan: Sorry about that - I usually cut&paste. I must admit I'm surprised how many answers and votes there are, willing to deconstruct an almost meaningless mistranslation (from a non-existent original, to boot). I for one will not be watching *George of the Jungle* in the interests of linguistic research! :)

Comment: Actually the sentence I wrote in the question is a sentence I found on Internet. I cannot remember where I read it, but I didn't invent a sentence just for asking a question.

Comment: @Kiam At least you have a complete breakdown on it in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*About* suggests approximation, so at approximately this time.  Most often used as an aside to the reader.

> About now you might be wondering why you should invest in […]"

Answer (score 3):

> What does about now mean, in the sentence?

"About now" means "at this time."

> Is it an informal way of saying?

Yes, this is informal speech or writing. I think this kind of writing style is common in email messages when the writer is guessing the mood of the recipient.

Answer (score 3):

The text comes from George of the Jungle

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119190/quotes

> [Translating with a Swahili phrasebook]
>
> Lyle: Pardon me, girls. I know you're feeling pretty hey sailor up
> here about now.  But if you would just let me order a bowl of fried
> clams we can all have smallpox tomorrow morning.

So it is a tourist using a poor guidebook that renders a possibly innocent request into something rude as in the famous [Dirty Hungarian Phrasebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Hungarian_Phrasebook)'s request for matches become *do you want to go to my place -- bouncy-bouncy?*

My take on this sentence is:

- Feeling pretty *something* : quite; very: The wind blew pretty hard.
- About now - I feel pretty tired about now = I feel quite tired at this time
- "Hey sailor, up here" - prostitutes calling from a balcony to sailors down below.

Result:

*Pardon me girls, I know by now you want me to have paid sex with you, but I am very hungry so I will eat now and have unprotected sex with you tomorrow which will spread, among us all, a horrible disease brought to indigenous populations by sailors*

Comment: That is _turn about_, not _about now_. You can say "she looked about the room," but that doesn't mean that "about the room" means "look about the room."

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with @moici's answer on this: "About" is commonly used informally to (ironically) *emphasize* the word it modifies and so does not mean "approximately" in this sense.

> I am about sick of this music.

does not mean that I am "nearly" or "approximately" sick, but rather that I am thoroughly sick of it. Likewise:

> I know you're feeling pretty hey sailor up here about now.

Should be translated:

> I know you're feeling pretty hey sailor up here *right now*.

Comment: or perhaps even 'right about now'.

Answer (score 0):

Good deductive work from @mplungjan, but, in general, "about now" can almost always be replaced with "now" without loss of meaning.